# Strange issue on ipad

Tags: ipad

After using my app for sometime.Suddenly, few of the images disappear.Instead, I can see a black screen.Even the wall paper of ipad disappears.Please help!

My screen has image view with some image, next & previous button.Everytime user presses next/previous button audio file plays & image changes.If I am using it for a long time.I cannot see some of the images, while I can hear the audio file

Comment: You need to specify your problem, you're not giving enough information for anyone to be able to help you. It sounds to me like memory exhaustion, but without any further details, I can't say.

Comment: I have got a screen with an image , previous & next button.Every time user presses next/or previous button, audio file plays & image changes.If I am using it for very long time.I cannot see some of the image, I get a black screen

Comment: Sounds like a memory issue. Run it with leaks and see what you find.

Comment: i am unable to run it with instruments.I get Target failed to run, remote exception encountered

Answer (score 0):

Its because of memory shortage.I fixed this issue by removing various leaks.Hope it helps!